# What's a word like "smart-arse" but for someone who DOESN'T actually know better?

Tags: word-request

I'm not totally sure about that, but it feels to me calling someone a "smart-arse" is like saying they are **annoying but are actually right**.

Is there any similar word without the subtle positive vibe that I can use to address someone who is **annoying and also wrong**?

Answer (score 4):

The word **smart-arse** or **smart-ass** doesn't always mean the person is right. They might be or might not be. They pretend like they know everything and boast which may vary from case-to-case.

[Lexico defines smart-arse as](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/smart-ass) *A person who is irritating because they behave as if they know everything.* ("smart-ass" is the North American version).

The opposite of the above word informally would be **dumbass**. Though both words are better off during an informal talk.

[Lexico defines dumbass as](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/dumbass) *A stupid or contemptible person.* (The British version is just "[arse](https://www.lexico.com/definition/arse)")

Comment: Hi Dhanistha - I edited your answer to include the definitions your Google search links pointed to. If you think I made too many changes, you can rollback the edit in the revision history, which you can get to by clicking the "edited" link to the left of your profile.

Comment: @ColleenV That's not a problem. I would actually like to thank you for including the meanings/definitions in a written format beside the link. I was actually working a late night and hence was too tired for that extra typing part. Thanks.